# stop code execution from external file call

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is a nodejs setup. The goal is to prevent some part of code execution if user is not in admin group:

This is in file1.js:

```
export function adminAuthRequired( req, res) {
if ( req.session.user_group !== "admin") {
    const message = "You are not  authorized to access this content."

    boundaries.redirectToPage( res, message, "redirect-default-page.ejs")

}
```

}

This is file2.js that calls the function from file1.js:

```
public destroy( slug ) {
    utils.adminAuthRequired( this.req, this.res) // Here we include file1 function
    // Code needs to stop execution here if user is not admin

    // Query db for user details
    db.deleteSingleRecord( this.res, "links", `WHERE link_slug = ${slug}`, callback )

    // ... rest of code....
}
```

Is there anyway to stop code execution after adminAuthRequired call in file2? With the execution stop handled in file1 ?

I could simply do an if statement in file2 on a bool returned from file 1, but I wish to know if there is a way to embed it all in file1?

Comment: You could create a function in file2.js that's called "executeAsAdmin" and pass a function as an argument that is defined in file1.js but is executed in file2.js, and only if the user is an admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the callback approach..

eg.

```
export function adminAuthRequired( req, res, cb) {
    if ( req.session.user_group !== "admin") {
        const message = "You are not  authorized to access this content."
        boundaries.redirectToPage( res, message, "redirect-default-page.ejs")
    } else cb();
}
```

and then call like ->

```
public destroy( slug ) {
   utils.adminAuthRequired( this.req, this.res, function() {
      db.deleteSingleRecord( this.res, "links", `WHERE link_slug = ${slug}`, callback );
      // ... rest of code....
   });
}
```